# Scroll to last row of rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have rendered a `rhandsontable` object inside a fixed-height container, as in the example shiny `server.R` file below, where `df` is some arbitrary `data.frame`. Every time `df` is updated I would like to automatically scroll the table to the last row. Can this be done?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(df, height=500)
  })
})
```